# set variables in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Say there are two variables: `x` and `y`. Let `x` be a function of `y`, e.g. `set x 2 * y`.

If future lines of the code alter the value of `y`, the value of `x` does not seem to automatically update, without me specifying again: `set x 2 * y`.

Is it possible to create a variable as a function of other variables, which automatically updates without having to set it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using variables for this, you should define a reporter:

```
to-report x
  report 2 * y
end
```

though, for the sake of those reading your code and for your future self looking back at your code, use more descriptive variable names than `x` and `y` :)